# Widget doesn't work when reboot the phone?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I have a widget that works well. All is ok unless I restart the phone. If I restart the phone, the widget don't show any data. I search here to some answer but all that I've found don't works for me.

Someone can a take a look to my code and tell me where is the problem??

Thanks in advance.

This is my class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra(WIDGET_IDS_KEY_RIGHT)) {
        int[] ids = intent.getExtras().getIntArray(WIDGET_IDS_KEY_RIGHT);
        if (intent.hasExtra(WIDGET_DATA_KEY_RIGHT)) {
            Object data = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(WIDGET_DATA_KEY_RIGHT);
            this.update(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), ids, data);
        } else {
            this.onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), ids);
        }
    } else super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.hasExtra(WIDGET_IDS_KEY_LEFT)) {
        int[] ids = intent.getExtras().getIntArray(WIDGET_IDS_KEY_LEFT);
        if (intent.hasExtra(WIDGET_IDS_KEY_LEFT)) {
            Object data = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(WIDGET_DATA_KEY_LEFT);
            this.update(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), ids, data);
        } else {
            this.onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), ids);
        }
    } else super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.hasExtra(WIDGET_IDS_KEY_CENTRAL)) {
        int[] ids = intent.getExtras().getIntArray(WIDGET_IDS_KEY_CENTRAL);
        if (intent.hasExtra(WIDGET_IDS_KEY_CENTRAL)) {
            Object data = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(WIDGET_DATA_KEY_CENTRAL);
            this.update(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), ids, data);
        } else {
            this.onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), ids);
        }
    } else super.onReceive(context, intent);

}


@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);

    startWidgetUpdateService(context);
}

protected static void startWidgetUpdateService(Context context) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    update(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds, null);

}

public void update(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager, int[] ids, Object data) {

    for (int appWidgetId : ids) {

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        numberRight = preferences.getString(HmApplication.PREF_NUMBER_RIGHT, "");
        numberCentral = preferences.getString(HmApplication.PREF_NUMBER_CENTRAL, "");
        numberLeft = preferences.getString(HmApplication.PREF_NUMBER_LEFT, "");

        Intent callIntentRight = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntentRight.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + numberRight));
        Intent callIntentCentral = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntentCentral.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + numberCentral));
        Intent callIntentLeft = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntentLeft.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + numberLeft));

        PendingIntent pendingIntentRight = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntentRight, 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentCentral = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntentCentral, 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentLeft = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntentLeft, 0);


        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        isCheckedOne = preferences.getBoolean(HmApplication.PREF_CHECKBOX_ONE, false);
        isCheckedTwo = preferences.getBoolean(HmApplication.PREF_CHECKBOX_TWO, false);
        isCheckedThree = preferences.getBoolean(HmApplication.PREF_CHECKBOX_THREE, false);



        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget);



        if(isCheckedOne == true){

            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget_one);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.actionButtonLeft, Main.textNamePhoneLeft);
        }

        if(isCheckedTwo == true){
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget_two);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.actionButtonLeft, Main.textNamePhoneLeft);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.actionButtonCentral, Main.textNamePhoneCentral);
        }


            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButtonRight, pendingIntentRight);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButtonCentral, pendingIntentCentral);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButtonLeft, pendingIntentLeft);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.actionButtonLeft, Main.textNamePhoneLeft);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.actionButtonCentral, Main.textNamePhoneCentral);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.actionButtonRight, Main.textNamePhoneRight);

            manager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}

public void updateMyWidgets(Context context) {
    AppWidgetManager man = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] ids = man.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class));

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    numberRight = preferences.getString(HmApplication.PREF_NUMBER_RIGHT, "");
    numberCentral = preferences.getString(HmApplication.PREF_NUMBER_CENTRAL, "");
    numberLeft = preferences.getString(HmApplication.PREF_NUMBER_LEFT, "");

    Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
    updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    updateIntent.putExtra(SimpleWidgetProvider.WIDGET_IDS_KEY_RIGHT, ids);
    updateIntent.putExtra(SimpleWidgetProvider.WIDGET_DATA_KEY_RIGHT, numberRight);
    updateIntent.putExtra(SimpleWidgetProvider.WIDGET_IDS_KEY_CENTRAL, ids);
    updateIntent.putExtra(SimpleWidgetProvider.WIDGET_DATA_KEY_CENTRAL, numberCentral);
    updateIntent.putExtra(SimpleWidgetProvider.WIDGET_IDS_KEY_LEFT, ids);
    updateIntent.putExtra(SimpleWidgetProvider.WIDGET_DATA_KEY_LEFT, numberLeft);
    context.sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
}
```

This is my manifest:

```
   <receiver android:name=".SimpleWidgetProvider"
        android:label="myWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/simple_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver and onRecieve method call your method `updateMyWidgets` to updated the widget

You need to define a receiver in manifest with action name `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

```
<!-- Start the Service if applicable on boot -->
<receiver android:name="com.test.MyReceiver ">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Make sure also to include the completed boot permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Now implement the reciever

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       YourClass.updateMyWidgets();// you may need to make this method static.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, can you give me a short code of this imolementation that you tell me.. I've tryed but doesn't work...